# Student class and objects

Tags: java, object

I am trying to write a program that takes a students name, and prints out the student's test scores along with their name. So far, the program displays `null` for the student name and "0" for the test scores. 
I have assigned value to the variables I am using but it seems to just skip over it. Here is the code:

```
package studentTestScores;
public class Student {

  public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    Student s1, s2;
    String str;
    int i;

    s1 = new Student();

    s1.setName("Bill");
    s1.setScore(1, 84);
    s1.setScore(2, 86);
    s1.setScore(3, 88);

    str = s1.getName();
    System.out.println(str);

    i = s1.getHighScore();
    System.out.println(i);

   }

   public void setScore(int i, int j) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }

   public int getHighScore() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return 0;
   }

   public String getName() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return null;
   }

   public void setName(String string) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }
}
```

Comment: What is inside your setName function

Comment: Nothing, the quick fix in eclipse suggested creating a public void so I tried it, it got rid of the error message, but nothing else.

Comment: is this Homework?  and ya what your setName function is doing?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hope this is what the program you need.

```
package studentTestScores;
public class Student {

public int highScore;
public string studentName;
public int subjectNum;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Student s1;
    String str;
    int i;

    s1 = new Student();

    s1.highScore = 0;
    s1.studentName = "";
    s1.subjectNum = 0;

    s1.setName("Bill");
    s1.setScore(1, 84);
    s1.setScore(2, 86);
    s1.setScore(3, 88);

    str = s1.getName();
    System.out.println(str);

    i = s1.getHighScore();
    System.out.println(i);

}

 public void compareAndSetHighScore(int i, int j) {
     if(highScore < j)
     {
        highScore = j;
        subjectNum = i;//If you need to print subject Number too.
     }
 }

 public int getHighScore() {
     return highScore;
 }

 public String getName() {
     return studentName ;
 }

 public void setName(String string) {
     studentName = string;
 }
```

}

Comment: That helped. The only problem now is that Java doesn't recognize the s1.setScore(int,int) as a valid command. It keeps wanting to create a method for setScore.